# Using Data Scraping Scripts The Right Way

Tags: php, curl, automation, screen-scraping

I am playing around with data scraping scripts. For now I am starting with PHP/cURL. Reason one I am interested in learning this is to learn how these are designed to help protect my own websites against those sneaky malicious ones. The second reason is to design these in a way that acts like a human for the purpose of avoiding undue burden on a website owners server.

If I use this in real life, it would be simply to use it to automate what I currently already do manually but I don't want to abuse this process however, I am a bit lazy so rather not do it manually.

To perform like a human:
1) Send header that look like a browser.
2) Send a referrer that represents the source of the link (sequence of pages).
3) Create delays randomized similar to how a human would search per page fetch.
4) Clear cookies when done. (Have to learn more about this, not sure how cookies function in a web scraper environment)

If the tools used above are done correctly, is IP Proxy switching necessary? Are there any other considerations I should be aware? Still learning about this so just curious at this point.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's going to be a lot of variance between different sites. In my experience building a scraper for a couple dozen sites in a particular niche, there wasn't much if anything as far as specific anti-scraper protection that needed bypassing. But that would be a very different story on, say, a popular game site, or SO itself.

Comment: I appreciate that info. I think I am gearing this with the expectation of the sites that have measures in place. If possible I would like to avoid having to do the whole IP proxy switching but I also don't want my IP to get banned which if used, I would rather use the site as if I was searching it, with my habits, time delays, correct link trails and to avoid putting any undue or unexpected espenditures on the servers hosting the site. 

Not sure if this is a realistic expectation though.